# Remove apostrophe from greek subfloat numbering

Tags: numbering, subfloats, minipage, greek

I run this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage{alphabeta,csquotes}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{eng_comp:a}\includegraphics[scale=.5]{plots/comp_og.png}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{eng_comp:b}\includegraphics[scale=.5]{plots/N3.png}}
\end{minipage}\par\medskip
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{eng_comp:c}\includegraphics[scale=.5]{plots/N4.png}}

\caption{Σύγκριση χάρτη των καμπυλών για α) 2 κινητήρες, β) 3 κινητήρες και γ) 4 κινητήρες}
\label{fig:eng_comp}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And I get this:

[image]

I would like to remove the apostrophe from the numbering and instead of (α') to get (α). Any suggestions?

Comment: You might declare your own custom counter without the kerala and use it with enumitem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no option for removing the apostrophe, called `\textdexiakeraia`.

At your own risk, you can nullify the command.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{alphabeta,csquotes}
\usepackage{subfig}

\renewcommand\textdexiakeraia{}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]

\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{eng_comp:a}\fbox{IMAGE}}%\includegraphics[scale=.5]{plots/comp_og.png}}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{eng_comp:b}\fbox{IMAGE}}%\includegraphics[scale=.5]{plots/N3.png}}
\end{minipage}\par\medskip
\centering
\subfloat[]{\label{eng_comp:c}\fbox{IMAGE}}%\includegraphics[scale=.5]{plots/N4.png}}

\caption{Σύγκριση χάρτη των καμπυλών για α) 2 κινητήρες, β) 3 κινητήρες και γ) 4 κινητήρες}
\label{fig:eng_comp}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I commented out the image inclusion, because I can't use yours.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "at my own risk"? What other implications does this may have?

Comment: @GiaFil7 Maybe the command is used elsewhere. I believe to have already seen the problem, but, if I remember correctly, the code in `greek.ldf` has changed since. I hoped the maintainers of the package would add an option for removing the symbol that many people (as my experience says) don't want. Alas, they didn't. Anyway, it seems quite specific to typesetting Greek numerals, so the risks should be quite low.